# postfix sender mailaddress rewrite based on recipient mailaddress

Tags: postfix, rewrite

I use postfix to send out mails to my contacts. Usually I use the info address for this and I've set a rule to rewrite my internal address into a valid mail address. So for example me@localhost gets rewritten in info@example.com.
Some contacts however know a different address of my domain and I use this to contact them. This involves manual setting the sender address. Not a big hassle but sometimes I just forget to do this. A few contacts get confused if I send mail from an address they don't know. So I just wonder is it possible to automatically rewrite the sender address based on the recipient address? Ofcourse I need to keep the rule that rewrites my internal address to a valid external address but I guess it needs some modifications. There are a few tutorials on the SE sites but they're all a bit different than what I want.